# Image management and scaling

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I am developing a live wallpaper and I would like to know how to manage high quality images. I am quite new to android development by the way.
I got 2 questions:

1)The image I use for wallpaper creation is a vector image (2560w x 1600h, 32bit, 10mb exactly), very crispy and with really high resolution. I tried it as a wallpaper and it looks just fantastic (on my tablet). I placed it in the `drawable` folder. This results in a high dimension `.apk` file (9 Mb). **Is it ok to have files this big enlarge apk dimension or it is a good practice to reduce it as much as possible?**

2)When building my wallpaper from the `Engine` class **i'd like to know, after setting the above image as a wallpaper, what is the best practice to scale it fitting XY independant of screen sizes.**

*PS: What i found to be perfect was the default system android use when you attempt to set an image as wallpaper. What does the system do in that case?*

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.)Since no android device supports resoultion bigger than 1280x760 of what I know, it is not a good practice in having images with bigger size than this as they use a lot of space for nothing.

2.)The [DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) class has everything you need related to this problem.

Comment: My asus transformer has a resolution of 1280x800 pixels. And i remember that setting an image (also with antialiasing set to true) of that resolution as wallpaper resulted in a blurry image so i tought about getting a bigger image with the same ratio and downscale that.

Comment: Well, I wasn't sure about the biggest resolution there is, but if you find it, and use that as your image resolution, there will be no problems such as blur or anything like it. Rescaling to a bigger resolution, no matter how good it is, it will still have down effects on your image's quality.